# Wildcard in route attribute for webApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In my webApi I have all methods located in one controller with routes attached to every method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/Users/Notary/Seal/Generate")]
public IHttpActionResult GenerateNotarySeal([FromBody]GenerateSealContract SealInfo)
{
    return Ok(new RestResponse<byte[]>(buffer));
}
```

When I test my webApi in swagger it does a preflight OPTIONS request to make sure "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" is set right. To send a response to this, I do something like:

```
[HttpOptions]
[Route("api/Users/Notary/Seal/Generate")]
public IHttpActionResult OptionsHandler([FromBody]GenerateSealContract SealInfo)
{
    ///.... I set my custom headers in ActionFilterAttribute           
    return Ok();
}
```

But I do not want to duplicate this code for every method. Is there any way to do a wildcard for just the OPTIONS requests? Something like:

```
[HttpOptions]
[Route("api/*")]
public IHttpActionResult OptionsHandler()
{
    ///.... I set my custom headers in ActionFilterAttribute           
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: You really don’t need to handle OPTIONS this way. It’s built-in to ASP.NET WebApi. See [here](https://enable-cors.org/server_aspnet.html) for more on how to set it up.

Comment: @KirkLarkin That's exactly what I've been looking for! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First I think you should check the regular attribute routing constrains found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-constraints)

Secondly what you want to do can be done but you have to implement your own [Custom Route Constraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#custom-route-constraints) but it probably won't be a wildcard (*) symbol.

From Microsoft docs links above:

> You can create custom route constraints by implementing the IHttpRouteConstraint interface. For example, the following constraint restricts a parameter to a non-zero integer value.

```
public class NonZeroConstraint : IHttpRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(HttpRequestMessage request, IHttpRoute route, string parameterName, 
        IDictionary<string, object> values, HttpRouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        object value;
        if (values.TryGetValue(parameterName, out value) && value != null)
        {
            long longValue;
            if (value is long)
            {
                longValue = (long)value;
                return longValue != 0;
            }

            string valueString = Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (Int64.TryParse(valueString, NumberStyles.Integer, 
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out longValue))
            {
                return longValue != 0;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

> The following code shows how to register the constraint:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        var constraintResolver = new DefaultInlineConstraintResolver();
        constraintResolver.ConstraintMap.Add("nonzero", typeof(NonZeroConstraint));

        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(constraintResolver);
    }
}
```

> Now you can apply the constraint in your routes:

```
[Route("{id:nonzero}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetNonZero(int id) { ... }
```

You can also implement a custom [ActionFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) where you have access to the HttpRequst including the request headers

```
public class CustomActionFilter: ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            // Before Execution

        }

        public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
        {
            //On Execution
        }
    }
```

Then you can apply the CustomActionFilter

- Controller Level
- Action Level
- Global Level: By registering it globally in web api config

Comment: wow, this seem like too much code for a very trivial function I'm looking for. Is there a way to do this easier maybe by implementing filters?

Comment: Yes, I think you can also create your own custom ActionFilter and either apply it globally in web api config, or on the controller level.